# How to make android APP as launcher conditionally

Tags: android

I have two android apps

1. one is for user type 1, it's a launcher app, the user will use this app as a default launcher
2. The second one is a regular app for user type 2, the user opens the app and uses.

After onwards I have merged two apps into a single app. It's all working fine. But both the users are seeing a screen like this choose which app to be a launcher

[image]

Can anyone tell me is it possible to make the app as launcher only for user type 1?

Answer (score 0):

You can declare  the launcher component (i.e. the activity receiving the HOME intent) as disabled :

```
<activity
    android:name="my.launcher.Class"
    android:enabled="false"
    ... >

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Then programatically enable it for user 1, using [PackageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager#setComponentEnabledSetting(android.content.ComponentName,%20int,%20int)) :

```
ComponentName cn = ComponentName.unflattenFromString("my.app.id/my.launcher.Class")

packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(cn,
    PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
    PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP)
```